# How to get the implicit reads from an object defined of some type?

Tags: scala, play-json

I have an implicit defined for `Reads[Seq[SomeCaseClass]]` in an object:

```
implicit object myReadsObj extends Reads[Seq[SomeCaseClass]] {
    override def reads(js: JsValue): JsResult[Seq[SomeCaseClass]] = js match {
      // resulting JsResult[Seq[SomeCaseClass]]
    }
 }
```

How do I extract the `Reads` from it to pass as an implicit to other function asking for `Reads`, `reads:Reads[Seq[A]]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that this answers the question, but `myReadsObj` will be used as the `Reads` in the following code:

```
case class SomeCaseClass()

implicit object myReadsObj extends Reads[Seq[SomeCaseClass]] {
  override def reads(js: JsValue): JsResult[Seq[SomeCaseClass]] =
    JsSuccess(Seq(SomeCaseClass()))
}

val j = Json.parse("""{ "hello": "world" }""")
j.validate[Seq[SomeCaseClass]]
```

Comment: Would rather use factory than implementing by inheritance as object: 1. Avoid variance with an explicit type class instance, 2. Easier; `val r: Reads[T] = Reads[T] { json => result }`

Comment: I tend to agree. The best would be just to use the OOTB `Json.format[SomeCaseClass]`. But I went along the the POs question.

Comment: `Json.reads` to only `Reads`, but anyway, inheritance for typeclass introduce unnecessary complexity/risk